KDE lockscreen (kscreenlocker_greet) high CPU usage
After KDE plasma 6 update, my CPU usage increased significantly while on lockscreen.
This caused the processor to reach high temperatures and lose electricity unnecessarily. Main processes that caused this were:
Xorg --nolisten tcp [...]    # ~ 60% CPU usage
kwin_x11 --replace           # ~ 40% CPU usage
kwin_x11 --replace           # ~ 20% CPU usage

I suspect it has something to do with the multi monitor setup.
Solution:
To fix this you need to:

go to system settings > Display and Monitor > Compositor
Uncheck Enable on startup
Confirm
Reboot

After that CPU usage on lockscreen goes back to normal.

https://bugs.kde.org/ Make sure you've tested the latest KDE release before filing a bug report. You can get it here: https://neon.kde.org/
